# require loop for sending mail thru excel

Tags: vba

```
Sub Mail_ActiveSheet()
' Works in Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010, Outlook 2000, Outlook 2002, Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007, Outlook 2010
    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
    Dim Destwb As Workbook
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim Subj As String
    Dim EmailAddr As String
    Dim cc As String
    Dim bcc As String
    Dim Body As String
    Dim Attment As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim X As String

    X = Range("B2").Select
    Do Until ActiveCell = ""
    company = ActiveCell
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    i = ActiveCell
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
    cemail = ActiveCell
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -3).Range("A1").Select
    EmailAddr = Range("L2")
    cc = Range("M2")
    bcc = Range("N2")
    Subj = Range("O2")
    Attment = Range("P2")
    Body = "Dear All," & vbLf _
    & vbLf _
    & "Request you to present the ECS as per the below details & Pl confirm after submission of the data file.  " & vbLf _
    & vbLf _
    & "CECS handover date                 :" & Range("I2") & vbLf _
    & vbLf _
    & "Settlement Date                       :" & Range("J2") & vbLf _
    & vbLf _
    & "Number of records                    :" & Range("F2") & vbLf _
    & vbLf _
    & "Total Contra Amount                 : " & Range("G2") & vbLf _
    & vbLf _
    & "Type of presentation                  : ECS Debit" & vbLf _
    & vbLf _
    & "Attachments                              : E-2 Form/Validation Reports/ECS data file" & vbLf _
    & vbLf _
    & "Thanks & Regards" & vbLf _
    & vbLf _
    & "GOBI L" & vbLf _
    & "ING VYSYA BANK LTD | CECS | 100, EDEN PARK | 20 VITTAL MALLYA ROAD | BANGALORE-560001 | PH :080-22532127 | "

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            .To = EmailAddr
            .cc = cc
            .bcc = bcc
            .Subject = Subj
            .Body = Body
            .Attachments.Add (Attment)
            .Display
        End With
        Loop

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: what have you tried to solve your problem? where does your code fail? where is the part responsible for iterating through sheets? what do you mean by *`i need to add loop for the below sheet so i can send many mails in single click for seperate persions in seperate mail`*? You are very unclear and you have not shown any effort at resolving your problem. We do NOT just write code for you, you are at a wrong place buddy. See [HOW TO ASK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: What is your question? When you last edited your post, you took the question out.

Answer (score 0):

Please read and respect the rules and take a good look on the link mehow provided.

---

As for your Problem, have you tried writing each recipient in a column, looping through the table and then sending the mail?

The table could look somewhat like this:

```
          A               B               C              
  +---------------+---------------+---------------+--- ...
1 | r1@foo.bar    : r2@foo.bar    : r3@foo.bar    |
2 | cc1@bar.foo   : cc2@bar.foo   : cc3@bar.foo   |
3 | bcc1@far.boo  : bcc2@far.boo  :               |
  +---------------+---------------+---------------+--- ...
4 | rr4@foo.bar   :               :               |
5 | cc4@bar.foo   : cc5@bar.foo   :               |
6 |               :               :               |
  +---------------+---------------+---------------+--- ...
```

Where in the first line you can put the recipients, in the second the CCs and in the third the BCCs. And in the 4th line it stats all over again with the recipients. Now you just have to loop through the table and send the mail.

---

Little hint on the side: you can use `Step 3` to increase the iterator by 3 (instead of 1) after an iteration.